# Error 3015004 when creating tokens in tutorial

Tags: cleos, c++

```
Caseys-MBP:eosio.token casey$ cleos push action eosio.token create '[ "eosio", "1000000000.0000 SYS"]' -p eosio.token@active
Error 3015004: The type defined in the ABI is invalid
Error Details:
account
Caseys-MBP:eosio.token casey$ cleos push action eosio.token create '{"issuer":"eosio", "maximum_supply":"1000000000.0000 SYS"}' -p eosio.token@active
Error 3015004: The type defined in the ABI is invalid
Error Details:
account
```

I get this error every time I try to create a token using the developers tutorial. I can't find a solution online.

I can deploy the contract fine in the step previously:

```
Caseys-MBP:eosio.token casey$ cleos set contract eosio.token /Users/casey/contracts/eosio.contracts/eosio.token --abi eosio.token.abi -p eosio.token@active
Reading WASM from /Users/casey/contracts/eosio.contracts/eosio.token/eosio.token.wasm...
Publishing contract...
executed transaction: b1baa91009caf28de48dbfdeab08e13f3deeb01a6eb89f1bd8d98bb69747ccee  9696 bytes  1663 us
#         eosio <= eosio::setcode               {"account":"eosio.token","vmtype":0,"vmversion":0,"code":"0061736d0100000001aa011c60037f7e7f0060047f...
#         eosio <= eosio::setabi                {"account":"eosio.token","abi":"0e656f73696f3a3a6162692f312e30000605636c6f73650002056f776e6572046e61...
warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet
```

ABI file for token:

```
{
    "____comment": "This file was generated with eosio-abigen. DO NOT EDIT Sat Oct 27 16:30:01 2018",
    "version": "eosio::abi/1.0",
    "structs": [
        {
            "name": "close",
            "base": "",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "owner",
                    "type": "name"
                },
                {
                    "name": "symbol",
                    "type": "symbol"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "create",
            "base": "",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "issuer",
                    "type": "name"
                },
                {
                    "name": "maximum_supply",
                    "type": "asset"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "issue",
            "base": "",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "to",
                    "type": "name"
                },
                {
                    "name": "quantity",
                    "type": "asset"
                },
                {
                    "name": "memo",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "open",
            "base": "",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "owner",
                    "type": "name"
                },
                {
                    "name": "symbol",
                    "type": "symbol"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ram_payer",
                    "type": "name"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "retire",
            "base": "",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "quantity",
                    "type": "asset"
                },
                {
                    "name": "memo",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "transfer",
            "base": "",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "from",
                    "type": "name"
                },
                {
                    "name": "to",
                    "type": "name"
                },
                {
                    "name": "quantity",
                    "type": "asset"
                },
                {
                    "name": "memo",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "types": [],
    "actions": [
        {
            "name": "close",
            "type": "close",
            "ricardian_contract": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "create",
            "type": "create",
            "ricardian_contract": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "issue",
            "type": "issue",
            "ricardian_contract": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "open",
            "type": "open",
            "ricardian_contract": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "retire",
            "type": "retire",
            "ricardian_contract": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "transfer",
            "type": "transfer",
            "ricardian_contract": ""
        }
    ],
    "tables": [
        {
            "name": "accounts",
            "type": "account",
            "index_type": "i64",
            "key_names": [],
            "key_types": []
        },
        {
            "name": "stat",
            "type": "currency_stats",
            "index_type": "i64",
            "key_names": [],
            "key_types": []
        }
    ],
    "ricardian_clauses": [],
    "abi_extensions": []
}
```

Comment: Could you please add details of your abi file?

Comment: Added the details above

Answer (score 1):

from the [issues page](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/issues/112) of eosio.contracts says that the file named `eosio.token.abi` is wrong, maybe bad code of `eosio.cdt`.

So, download the correct file, which you can found from the post, or just [click here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vchengsong/eosio.contracts/master/eosio.token/abi/eosio.token.abi) and overlay the file named `eosio.token.abi` generated by `eoscpp` in the `eosio.contract/eosio.token/`  and re-excute `cleos set contract ...`.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `account` and `currency_stats` in the `structs` part of your abi.

See https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/the-abi#section-explicit-structs for details and https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/the-abi#section-putting-it-all-together for a full abi of token contract.

Comment: I used the ABI file and I keep getting the same error

Comment: Verify that you have deployed the correct file by downloading the abi from the chain.

Comment: Could you guide me in how to do that?

Comment: For example deploy the file again with cleos and see whether it complains that the same code version is already running.